# Mock Service without using constructor with Autowire but use Java method

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, junit5

I want to edit this code to use mock for services. This code is working fine:

```
@Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;
    private Terminals terminal;

    @Autowired
    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(Terminals terminal, RiskFilterService riskFilterService) {  
        this.terminal = terminal;
        this.riskFilterService = riskFilterService;
    }

    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter(Terminals terminal) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {

        List<RiskFilters> filter_list = riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(terminal.getId(), "BinCountryCheckFilter");
    }
}
```

JUnit test:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest    {

    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() throws JsonProcessingException, JAXBException {
        //Arrange
        RiskFilterService riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);
        Terminals terminal = Mockito.mock(Terminals.class);

        BDDMockito.given(
            riskFilterService.findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(anyInt(), anyString()))
            .willReturn(riskFiltersList);

        int expectedInt = 11;
        String expectedString = "BinCountryCheckFilter";

        when(terminal.getId()).thenReturn(expectedInt);

        BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilterImpl = 
            new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(terminal, riskFilterService);

        //Act
        binCountryCheckFilterImpl.validateBinCountryCheckFilter();

        //Assert
        then(riskFilterService)
          .should()
          .findRiskFiltersByTerminalIdAndType(expectedInt, expectedString);
    }    
}
```

This code is NOT working:

```
    @Service
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("riskFilterService")
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    public Response validateBinCountryCheckFilter(Merchants merchant, Contracts contract, Terminals terminal,
              PaymentTransaction message, HttpServletRequest request) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
               ...........

    }

}
```

For some reason `riskFilterService` in null when I run the JUnit test. Is there some way to implement the service with the JUnit test properly?
In my case I don't want to call `terminal` from the constructor but from the Java method `validateBinCountryCheckFilter(...)` and `riskFilterService` as Autowired service.

The singleton bean BinCountryCheckFilterImpl cannot have the per-request value terminal as a field, i.e. as a parameter on the constructor when the code is deployed but it's working with the JUnit test. If the terminal value must be passed as a method parameter the JUnit code won't run.

Can you advice, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using JUnit4. The easiest way to do this is to use the `MockitoJUnitRunner` like this:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilter;

    @Mock
    private RiskFilterService riskFilterService;


    @Test
    public void testBinCountryCheckFilterImpl() {
        // test content
    }

}
```

To use JUnit 5 you would change the `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)` to `@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)`. Of course anything else like `@Test` used would also need to be from JUnit 5. But, the Mockito `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock` annotations are the same as JUnit 4.

However, you can also use the Spring `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` to set the field after you call the constructor with the mocked service. I prefer the first way over reflection, but this is closer to your current code.

```
riskFilterService = Mockito.mock(RiskFilterService.class);
binCountryCheckFilter = new BinCountryCheckFilterImpl();
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(binCountryCheckFilter, "riskFilterService", riskFilterService);
```

Comment: Yes, I think, it is the answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you show me a solution with JUnit 5, please?

Comment: I added the change needed for JUnit 5.

Comment: I have a question about this: `@InjectMocks
    private BinCountryCheckFilterImpl binCountryCheckFilter;` I added a Interface `BinCountryCheckFilter` implemented by `BinCountryCheckFilterImpl`. In that case how I have to change it?

Comment: You would just mock the interface instead of the class `@Mock BinCountryCheckFilter binCountryCheckFilter`. Mockito extends and/or implements whatever is passed to it. It can mock any class/interface/method that is not static or final.

Answer (score 0):

Change existing code to:

```
public class BinCountryCheckFilterImpl {
    private final RiskFilterService riskFilterService;

    public BinCountryCheckFilterImpl(@Qualifier("riskFilterService") RiskFilterService riskFilterService) {
        this.riskFilterService = riskFilterService;
    }


    public void validateBinCountryCheckFilter(......) throws JAXBException, JsonProcessingException {
                   .........................
        }
}
```